# MySQL Copy Table Data of one Database Table to another AUTOMATICALLY; as table gets updated or by some specific time interval, schedule

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services, subroutine

Copy Table Data of one Database Table to another AUTOMATICALLY; as table gets updated or by some specific time interval, schedule

Database MySQL; Language PHP

I've got TWO databases; A and B

Database A contains a table USERS

I want to copy table data of USERS to Database B; by some routine, service, scheduly after some specific time that can be set dynamically. Aim is to get table data automatically.

So, Database B will have USERS table data same as Database A

Answer (score 0):

If you need copy data from one table to another you could use [MySQL triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) called after INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE row in your source table.

If you nedd to copy data periodically you could use [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Another options is [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules-table-options.html) .